# How can I make my Javascript event handler execute just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of JS code to track if the user's mouse leaves the window. How would I make this event fire only once using jQuery? (Sorry, I'm new to Javascript and new to programming).

**Mouse Tracking Code:**

```
addEvent(document,"mouseout",function(e){
e = e ? e : window.event;
var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
if(!from || from.nodeName == "HTML"){
//cursor has left, add action here
window.location.href = '#popup1';
}
});
```

**I believe this is what I'm looking to implement to make the event fire just once:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").one("event", function(evt){
      //Your Code
    });
 });
```

Thank you!

Comment: .one would work... what example are you having issues with using it?

Comment: `e.target` is the property you want, the ones you use are flaky.

Comment: How do the shown `addEvent` and the `.one("event", ..)` relate?

Answer (score 1):

If your not using the `one()` function which should do exactly what you described you can do the same with `on()` and `off()`

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
    $( this ).off( event );
});
```

Comment: but `one()` only fires once so why would a flag be needed as well? Seems like code bloat

Comment: you are correct, i missed the usage of one() and assumed it's on(). Edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just do something like this?

```
$(window).one('mouseout', function () { 
   alert();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/20av9bnr/2/

Comment: got it, should be able to just use $(window) then, no?

Comment: well, i think that one() is like on() and thus fires on any descendant  element "mouseing out", so it would just cancel right away before the mouse got to the edge, which is why i went with a in-condition flag on my delegated answer, even though i'm not a huge fan of flags...